# Using the same model for View, Business and Data Layers

Tags: mvvm, view, model, entities

I had a very interesting discussion recently with a colleague. He only has years-long coding experience with no engineering background whatsoever. He seriously tried to persuade me that using the s**ame model for presentation, business, and persistence of entities** is actually considered a best-practice.

We work on the same project. It's basically a Web API that delivers JSON and uses a MongoDB database. For **all our entities**, the JSON response, the business classes in the code, and the MongoDB documents **all have the same structure**.

I think his approach is totally wrong. He argued that keeping those 3 things separated like in the MVVM and MVC patterns is old school thinking because everytime you create a new business entity, you must "write mapping code" for the JSON response as well as the mapping to MongoDB documents.

When it comes to designing business entities, his design approach is really strange: he never uses inheritance or aggregation/composition. His logic is this: "When I design business entities, I must keep frontend developers in mind. The JSON response must have a structure that is easily usable and accessible by frontend code."

All our business entities in the code, **and I mean all**, do not show any sign of inheritance, aggregation or composition. No associations whatsoever. Every time a new feature comes in, he "designs" a completely new entity. He also changes the structure of entities already running in production code (by adding new fields for new features), which not only has an impact on how the MongoDB documents are (and can) be loaded, it also has an effect on the JSON response. In other words, this completely messes up the stability of the code and the usability of the API.

What do you think?